how is a slackline elasticity in percent specified?
I tried to do some load and oscillations  calculations based on these equations and I have a question on how manufacturers specify elasticity.
It is often stated in % elongation E as a function of tension T (e.g.), but while doing simulations one needs to specify elongation constant k of Hook's law:
T = k (L-L0) = kEL0
where L0 is the length before tensioning and L after.
Thus tension is related to % elongation and length also!
My questions are:

is this correct ?
if yes at which length manufacturers specify elongation curve ? I can't find the info on any manufacturer website

Thanks!

Young Modulus. Have fun. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_modulus

Hook's law is wrong. In the same sense Newton was wrong. If ya need high precision higher harmonics need to be considered. Just decide what error margin is cool.
